# command line arguments segmentation fault

Tags: command-line, segmentation-fault, arguments, parameter-passing

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int first_arg, second_arg; 

    if( argv[1] == NULL || argv[2] == NULL ){
        printf("no arguments! ");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s  %s \n", argv[1], argv[2] );
        sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &first_arg);
        sscanf (argv[2], "%d", &second_arg);
        printf("%d  %d", first_arg, second_arg);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get int parameters. Program works with small number parameters but when I write big numbers it gives segmentation fault. I've tried to fix it with gdb, it says:

```
warning: `/private/var/tmp/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/libplatform.build/libsystem_platform.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/init.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
no arguments! [Inferior 1 (process 1275) exited normally]
```

it works with "100 and 1", "200 and 1" but "300 and 1" gives segmentation fault. also works "1 and 1000" but "10 and 1000" gives segmentation again. 
it prints only first printf in else

Comment: It works fine on my computer although I'm still using a 32-bit system.

Comment: Works fine on 64 bit linux; tell us about your environment, os & compiler.

Comment: How are you passing the arguments to GDB? Get that right and you should be able to investigate closer. The code *looks* ok to me.

Comment: Why don't you use `argc` to check for the arguments? Like `if (argc < 3)`